# System functions call in C

Tags: c, unix, operating-system

I can't understand why this piece of code does not work. Read() returns -1.
I opened file like this:

```
int descr = open(filepath, O_RDWR);
```

then I tried this:

```
void* bufi = malloc(blockSize);
void* bufj = malloc(blockSize);


//Loading to buffs
descr = lseek(descr, blockSize*i, SEEK_SET);

printf("%zd\n", read(descr, bufi, blockSize));

descr = lseek(descr, blockSize*j, SEEK_SET);

read(descr, bufj, blockSize);


//Writing from bufs to apropriate places in file
descr = lseek(descr, blockSize*j, SEEK_SET);

write(descr, bufi, blockSize);

descr = lseek(descr, blockSize*i, SEEK_SET);

write(descr, bufj, blockSize);
```

File I tried to open was treated with "chmod 777" in case that was a problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `read`, specifically how to tell what the actual error is? (Also, the code shown doesn't check the return values of functions like `open`, `read` and `write` *everywhere*. You need to fix that or your code will be much harder for you to understand.)

Comment: Of course I did. Errors will be checked when I see it works at all (the return values you mention). I did the same thing using functions fopen(), fread() etc. and all worked just fine.

Comment: So, did the `open` succeed? What was the error you got from `read`?

Comment: Also, don't do this: `printf("%zd\n", read(descr, bufi, blockSize));`. The call to `printf` might clear or overwrite the error code from `read`, causing you to be unable to get it or to get it incorrectly. Don't do any system calls (or functions that do system calls) between calling `read` and checking its return value and getting the error code. Once you've done all that, *then* call `printf` with the results. Perhaps `if (read(...)==-1) { int e = errno; printf(...); }`. (Notice no call to `printf` until after I got the error code, so no worries if `printf` changes it.)

Comment: The errno is 9. The file descriptor is not proper? Why? It opens successfully.

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? With the code shown, for example, we have no way to tell how you are determining that it opened successfully. So maybe you determined that incorrectly. Or maybe `descr` is being changed between the `open` and the `read`. We can't tell.

Comment: here you are:
http://pastebin.com/H739xuKm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int descr = open(filepath, O_RDWR);

descr = lseek(descr, blockSize*i, SEEK_SET);

printf("%zd\n", read(descr, bufi, blockSize));
```

By the time you get to `read`, you've changed the value of `descr` to be whatever `lseek` returned, which is very unlikely to be a valid file descriptor. Don't use `descr` to hold the value returned by `lseek`.

Comment: I see. My bad. Thanks a lot!